# LDAP: querying for all users in entire domain using sAMAccountName

Tags: python, active-directory, ldap

I have modified this code python-paged-ldap-snippet.py from https://gist.github.com/mattfahrner/c228ead9c516fc322d3a

My problem is that when I change my SEARCHFILTER from `'(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))'` to  `'(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(memberOf=CN=Users0,OU=Groups,DC=ad,DC=company,DC=com))'` 
it runs just fine.
If it is on `SEARCHFILTER='(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))'`, I notice that the code is not entering the writeToFile function.

The objective of the code is to dump all the user information and parse the info into a file.
I tried running LDAPSEARCH against `'(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))'` and I manage to get the output .
Not sure what is wrong. Suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import ldap
import os
 
LDAPSERVER='ldap://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:389'
BASEDN='dc=ad,dc=company,dc=com'
LDAPUSER = "CN=LDAPuser,OU=XXX,OU=Users,DC=ad,DC=company,DC=com"
LDAPPASSWORD = 'LDAPpassword'
PAGESIZE = 20000
ATTRLIST = ['sAMAccountName','uid']
SEARCHFILTER='(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))'
#SEARCHFILTER='(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(memberOf=CN=Users0,OU=Groups,DC=ad,DC=company,DC=com))'
data = []
 
ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT, ldap.OPT_X_TLS_ALLOW)
ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)
 
l = ldap.initialize(LDAPSERVER)
l.protocol_version = 3          # Paged results only apply to LDAP v3
try:
    l.simple_bind_s(LDAPUSER, LDAPPASSWORD)
    print ' Login Done, Searching data'
except ldap.LDAPError as e:
    exit('LDAP bind failed: %s' % e)

lc = ldap.controls.SimplePagedResultsControl(True,size=PAGESIZE,cookie='')

def writeToFile(data):
    print ' Writing data to file'
#code to print all output into CVS file

while True:
    try:
       msgid = l.search_ext(BASEDN, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, SEARCHFILTER, ATTRLIST, serverctrls=[lc])
    except ldap.LDAPError as e:
        sys.exit('LDAP search failed: %s' % e)
    try:
        rtype, rdata, rmsgid, serverctrls = l.result3(msgid)
    except ldap.LDAPError as e:
        sys.exit('Could not pull LDAP results: %s' % e)
 
    for dn, attrs in rdata:
        data.append(attrs)

    pctrls = [        
    c for c in serverctrls if c.controlType == ldap.controls.SimplePagedResultsControl.controlType        ]
    if not pctrls:
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Warning: Server ignores RFC 2696 control.'
        break
 
    cookie = pctrls[0].cookie
    if not cookie:
        writeToFile(data)
        print 'Task Complete'
        break
    lc.controlValue = (PAGESIZE, cookie)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PAGESIZE = 20000
```

Lower your page size to a value <= 1000, since [that's the max AD will give you at a time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/view-set-ldap-policy-using-ntdsutil#:%7E:text=Default%20value%3A%205-,MaxPageSize,-%2D%20This%20value%20controls) anyway. It's possible that it's waiting for 20000 records before requesting the next page and never getting it.